# Fixed menu hovering CSS style needed

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

When I am hovering on the part of the page where I created a fixed menu, it opens up, even that I am not hovering on the menu, but to the right of it.
Additionally I can't access the inputs in that part of the page (between the two black lines in the picture)
[image: Hovering brings the menu up, even when not hovering on the menu]

My code for the custom menu is:

```
CUSTOM NAVIGATION
================================================ */
#custom-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 99%;
  position: fixed;
  top:40%;
  left:10%;
  text-indent:15px;
  line-height:150%;
}
    #custom-nav li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/* custom level link */
#custom-nav a {
    display: block;
    color:#9a7283;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:159px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
}
/* custom level link :hover */
#custom-nav a:hover {
    background: #9a7283;
    color:#fff;
}

/* current link */
#custom-nav .current_page_item a, #custom-nav .current-menu-item a {
    background: #9a7283;
    color:#fff;
}

/* current link :hover */
#custom-nav .current_page_item a:hover, #custom-nav .current-menu-item a:hover {
    background: #9a7283;
    color:#fff;
}

/* sub-levels link */
#custom-nav ul a, #custom-nav .current_page_item ul a, #custom-nav ul .current_page_item a, #custom-nav .current-menu-item ul a, #custom-nav ul .current-menu-item a, #custom-nav li:hover > ul         a  {
    padding:10px;
    line-height:150%;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
/* sub-levels link :hover */
#custom-nav ul a:hover, #custom-nav .current_page_item ul a:hover, #custom-nav ul .current_page_item a:hover, #custom-nav .current-menu-item ul a:hover, #custom-nav ul .current-menu-item a:hover, #custom-nav li:hover > ul a:hover {
}
/* dropdown ul */
#custom-nav ul {
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
    top:5px;
    left:146px;
}
#custom-nav ul li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
/* sub-levels dropdown */
#custom-nav ul ul {
}
/* show dropdown ul */
#custom-nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also paste the `html` or create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a `width` to your container `div`, i am just naming it.

```
.container{
width: 150px; /* according to your requirement */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of `#custom-nav` is set to `99%`.  Instead set the `width` to a fixed width that is the size of the actual content.